# How to use bitnami drupal image with external database

Tags: docker, drupal, bitnami

I have created a docker file that uses the bitnami drupal image and I am trying to Create a database for Drupal using mysql-client, with no luck. This is my dockerfile:

```
 FROM bitnami/drupal:9.0.2

ENV DRUPAL_SITE_NAME="something" \
    DRUPAL_USERNAME="something" \
    DRUPAL_PASSWORD="something" \
    DRUPAL_EMAIL="something" \
    MYSQL_CLIENT_DATABASE_HOST="something" \
    MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD="something" \
    MYSQL_CLIENT_PORT_NUMBER="3306" \
    MYSQL_CLIENT_ROOT_USER="root" \
    MYSQL_CLIENT_ROOT_PASSWORD="something" \
    MYSQL_CLIENT_CREATE_DATABASE_NAME="something" \
    MYSQL_CLIENT_CREATE_DATABASE_USER="something" \
    MYSQL_CLIENT_CREATE_DATABASE_PASSWORD="something" \
    ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD="no"  \
    PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT="512"

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    git \
    default-mysql-client \
    vim \
    wget &&\
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" &&\
    php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e5325b19b381bfd88ce90a5ddb7823406b2a38cff6bb704b0acc289a09c8128d4a8ce2bbafcd1fcbdc38666422fe2806') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" &&\
    php composer-setup.php &&\
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" &&\
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

but I get The MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD environment variable is empty or not set.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you getting that message? The `MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD` isn't listed in https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-drupal#environment-variables Why are you setting it?

Comment: Hi Ale I am setting it because I want to connect to an external database and not create a mariadb instance using docker-compose. I used the variables listed in the documentation but I get an error:
ERROR ==> The MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD environment variable is empty or not set. Set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes to allow the container to be started with blank passwords. This is recommended only for development.